# Unable to import NumPy module from EFS in lambda

Tags: python, numpy, aws-lambda, scipy, amazon-efs

I have an AWS EFS filesystem, in which I have installed different packages including numpy and scipy. All the packages are installed in pkgs folder, created within the root folder of EFS.

To download the package I am using following command:

> pip3 install numpy -t /path/in/efs

Similarly I have downloaded other packages, I also verified that packages are installed in /pkgs folder.
[image: Image form EFS]

I have mounted this EFS Filesystem to AWS Lambda, I am importing these packages in lambda using PYTHONPATH.

I have mounted the path on /mnt/access in lambda function. The access point and lambda contains all necessary permissions required to import the package and execute it.

While executing(importing) the numpy packages it returns error as mentioned below:

> [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'handler': Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there.

While importing other packages it didn't returned any error, it ran successfully.

Any help will be appreciated.